# Recognizing Dell EquilLogic with Nagios

Tags: linux, dell, nagios

EDIT: All firmware and models are compatible, that is why nothing is posted about it.

Okay, so there will be a lot here, so please bear with me. I've been working on this now for a few hours (reading manuals and such) so I'm not just coming here right out of the blue. I am working on a PRE-EXISTING Nagios server where there are several other existing plugins and checks running and working. Now I want to add another server there to check so I made the following modifications:

First and foremost, I added a file to /usr/local/nagios/libexec named: check_equallogic.sh. The permissions are 755, the same as all others. I have chowned to nagios:nagios and in the listing it shows the Owner as Nagios.

I then added a command to the commands.cfg file in \usr\local\nagios\etc\objects that shows the following:

```
# 'check_equallogic' command definition
define command{
    command_name check_equallogic
    command_line $USER1$/check_equallogic -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -C $ARG1$ -t $ARG2$ $ARG3$
}
```

Following this, I created a file named equallogic.cfg in the objects directory and it contains (more or less):

```
define host{
    use     linux-server        ; Inherit default values from a template
    host_name   172.16.50.11        ; The name we're giving to this device
    alias       EqualLogic      ; A longer name associated with the device
    address     172.16.50.11        ; IP address of the device
    contact_groups       admins
}
```

## Check Equallogic Information

```
define service{
    use                 generic-service
    host_name           172.16.50.11
    service_description         General Information
    check_command               check_equallogic!public!info
}
```

After ensuring that permissions are okay for all files, I restart the nagios service, no errors. When I go into the WebGUI, I get the following errors AFTER the check runs:

(Return code of 127 is out of bounds - plugin may be missing)

Extra, probably unrelated problem

Furthermore, when I log into the Equallogic server, under Audit logs I get the following error:

```
Level: AUDIT
Time:  26/05/2014 3:59:13 PM
Member:  ps4100-1
Subsystem:  agent
Event ID:  22.7.1
SNMP packet validation failed, request received from 172.16.10.11
```

An snmpwalk receives a timeout, whereas others succeed. I will work on importing the MIBs tomorrow. The reason why I am mentioning it is because I want to make sure that it is only a MIB issue for the SNMP. If it is, then ignore this area.

I am entirely unsure of what to do here.

Answer (score 0):

127 means "file not found". Verify that `USER1` is set to "/usr/local/nagios/libexec" in the resources file.

Perhaps more importantly: You said the script is named `check_equallogic.sh` but your command definition says just `check_equallogic` without the ".sh" extension.